# Make Ubercart Attributes set price, not change the price

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I have been searching for this all over the internet, but haven't came up with the solution just yet.

On my Drupal 7 installation I've happily used Ubercart for a while now, but I'm going to sell software from now on.
I'd like to use attributes to change the price based on the amount of computers and licence experiation date (years from now).
The prices don't always rise the same way, so I can't set an increase of 10% with every year.
I'd like to fill out a price table and when the user makes his choice, he gets the price right.

This is the website I'm talking about (example product): https://www.xsbyte.com/catalog/73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible to do this, you could fill out a new price for a new object, or could just make a new product, but that was not what I was looking for.
I ended up using WooCommerce (Wordpress) and integrated both systems, so customers get features like single-logon and shared customer address and payment details (if applicatable).